# Is there a rating system JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript, rating

I did a Google search and found this [touchwipe jQuery plugin](http://www.netcu.de/jquery-touchwipe-iphone-ipad-library), which looks pretty good.
It looks like it will do what I want it to do.

My question is: am I going down a wrong path? Would someone who knew what they were talking about say to me something like:

> Why are you using touchwipe? You should be using (blank) like *everybody
>   else* is using!

This goes for everything new I'm trying to learn. For instance, I think [noUISlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/) is a pretty sweet plugin, but who's to say? Is there a rating system for JavaScript functions?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no reliable, centralized, system for javascript libraries, or really jQuery libraries. But there are well-known jQuery plugins like jQuery-ui which are considered standard.

It seems like you want to implement mobile touch events in mobile browsers. Try the [Hammer](http://hammerjs.github.io/) library. No dependencies, and <4kb minified so it's ideal for mobile. I try to avoid jQuery on mobile because it's so big that it can slow the browser significantly on some phones.

Comment: I think I tried Hammer a year or so ago and it would drop the browser completely out of memory after about 20 or so swipes.

Comment: Maybe I should try it again.